# Windows: Apache Spark History Server Config

Tags: windows, git, bash, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to use Spark's History Server to make use of the logging mechanisms of my Web UI, but I find some difficulty in running this code on my Windows machine.

I have done the following:

Set my spark-defaults.conf file to reflect

```
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.eventLog.dir=file://C:/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs
spark.history.fs.logDirectory=file://C:/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs
```

My spark-env.sh to reflect:

```
SPARK_LOG_DIR    "file://C:/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs"
SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS   "-Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=file://C:/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs"
```

I am using Git-BASH to run the start-history-server.sh file, like this:

```
USERA@SYUHUH MINGW64 /c/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin
$ sh start-history-server.sh
```

And, I get this error:

```
USERA@SYUHUH MINGW64 /c/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin
$ sh start-history-server.sh
C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/spark-env.sh: line 69: SPARK_LOG_DIR: command not found
C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/spark-env.sh: line 70: SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS: command not found
ps: unknown option -- o
Try `ps --help' for more information.
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-SGPF02M9ZB.out
ps: unknown option -- o
Try `ps --help' for more information.
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer:
  Spark Command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java -cp C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/conf\;C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar;C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\lib\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar;C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\lib\datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar;C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\lib\datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar -Xms1g -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
  ========================================
full log in C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-SGPF02M9ZB.out
```

The full log from the output can be found below:

```
Spark Command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java -cp C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/conf\;C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar;C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\lib\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar;C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\lib\datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar;C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\lib\datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar -Xms1g -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
========================================
```

I am running a sparkR script where I initialize my spark context and then call init().

Please advise whether I should be running the history server before I run my spark script?

Pointers & tips to proceed(with respect to logging) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows you'll need to run the *.cmd* files of Spark not *.sh*. According to what I saw, there is no *.cmd* script for Spark history server. So basically it needs to be run manually.

I have followed the history server Linux script and in order to run it manually on Windows you'll need to take the following steps:

- All history server configurations should be set at the *spark-defaults.conf* file (remove `.template` suffix) as described below
- You should go to spark config directory and add the `spark.history.*` configurations to `%SPARK_HOME%/conf/spark-defaults.conf`. As follows:

  `spark.eventLog.enabled          true
   spark.history.fs.logDirectory   file:///c:/logs/dir/path`
- After configuration is finished run the following command from %SPARK_HOME%

  `bin\spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer`
- The output should be something like that:

  `16/07/22 18:51:23 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 18080.
   16/07/22 18:51:23 INFO HistoryServer: Started HistoryServer at http://10.0.240.108:18080
   16/07/22 18:52:09 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called`

Hope that it helps! :-)

Comment: I followed your advice & changed the lines to reflect "export.." & now I get this error: C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/spark-env.sh: line 69: export: `file://C:/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs': not a valid identifier & spark-env.sh: line 70: export: `- spark.history.fs.logDirectory=file://C:/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs': not a valid identifier. "

Comment: I'm not sure what I am missing here. I have a "logs" directory created & I run the history server command before my application starts..

Comment: Now I got it that you are running on Windows. spark-env.sh is a Linux script. I have amended my answer accordingly. Please also note that the file path format was missing a '/'. Should be three '/'. I have changed it in my answer. I would also try to put it in a different directory just for the sake of the test and make sure I have all the relevant permissions.

Comment: Thanks for writing back. As advised, I made the changes only to my spark-defaults.conf file. It only contains the lines: spark.eventLog.enabled      true
spark.eventLog.dir               file:///C:/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    file:///C:/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/logs       & when I use gitbash to run my "sh start-history-server.sh" command, I get the error as " ps: unknown option -- o.

Answer (score 0):

in case any one gets the floowing exception:

```
17/05/12 20:27:50 ERROR FsHistoryProvider: Exception encountered when attempting
 to load application log file:/C:/Spark/Logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.hist
ory.HistoryServer-1-Arsalan-PC.out
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Codec [out] is not available. Consider setti
ng spark.io.compression.codec=snappy
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$$anonfun$createCodec$1.apply(Com
```

Just go to SparkHome/config/spark-defaults.conf
and set 
 spark.eventLog.compress false