# Apache Spark: History server (logging) + non super-user access (HDFS)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-standalone

I have a working HDFS and a running Spark framework in a remote server. 
I am running SparkR applications and hope to see the logs of the completed UI as well. 
I followed all the instructions here: [Windows: Apache Spark History Server Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419493/windows-apache-spark-history-server-config)
and was able to start the History Server on the server.

However, only when the super-user(person who started the name node of Hadoop) and who started the Spark processes fires a Spark application remotely, the logging takes places successfully in HDFS path & we are able to view the History Web UI of Spark as well.

When I run the same application from my user ID (remotely), though it shows on port 18080 a History Server is up and running, it does not log any of my applications.

I have been given read, write and execute access to the folder in HDFS.

The spark-defaults.conf file now looks like this:

```
 spark.eventLog.enabled            true
 spark.history.fs.logDirectory     hdfs://XX.XX.XX.XX:19000/user/logs
 spark.eventLog.dir                hdfs://XX.XX.XX.XX:19000/user/logs
 spark.history.ui.acls.enable      false 
 spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled  true 
 spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval 1d
 spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge   7d
```

Am I missing out on some permissions or config settings somewhere(Spark? HDFS)?

Any pointers/tips to proceed from here would be appreciated.

Comment: Could someone please share their views and hunches on what could be missing? I can help provide the details of the permissions/ setup if needed.