# Spark History server setup

Tags: windows, apache-spark, spark-webui

I am trying to setup Spark History config server in local. I am using using Windows and Pycharm for Pyspark programming. I am able to view Spark Web-UI at localhost:4040.
The things I have done are:

1. spark-defaults.conf: (Where I have added last three lines.)

   ```
   #
   # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   # contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   # this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   # The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   # (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   # the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
   #
   #    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
   #
   # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   # limitations under the License.
   #

   # Default system properties included when running spark-submit.
   # This is useful for setting default environmental settings.

   # Example:
   # spark.master                     spark://master:7077
   # spark.eventLog.enabled           true
   # spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory
   # spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
   # spark.driver.memory              5g
   # spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
   spark.jars.packages                com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1
   spark.eventLog.enabled      true
   spark.history.fs.logDirectory   file:///D:///tmp///spark-events
   ```
2. Run the history server

   ```
    C:\Users\hp\spark>bin\spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    20/08/09 08:58:04 INFO HistoryServer: Started daemon with process name: 13476@DESKTOP-B9KRC6O
    20/08/09 08:58:23 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    20/08/09 08:58:23 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hp
    20/08/09 08:58:23 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hp
    20/08/09 08:58:23 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
    20/08/09 08:58:23 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
    20/08/09 08:58:23 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hp); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hp); groups with modify permissions: Set()
    20/08/09 08:58:24 INFO FsHistoryProvider: History server ui acls disabled; users with admin permissions: ; groups with admin permissions
    20/08/09 08:58:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 18080.
    20/08/09 08:58:26 INFO HistoryServer: Bound HistoryServer to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://DESKTOP-B9KRC6O:18080
   ```
3. After I run my Pyspark program successfully, I am unable to see Job details at Spark-History-server web UI. Though the server is started. It looks like below:

[image: The localhost:18080 Web UI]

4. The references I have already used:

   [Windows: Apache Spark History Server Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419493/windows-apache-spark-history-server-config/38420497#38420497)

   [How to run Spark History Server on Windows](https://medium.com/@eyaldahari/how-to-run-spark-history-server-on-windows-52cde350de07)
5. The code I use is as follows:

   ```
    from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("madhu").setMaster("local")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    spark = SparkSession(sc).builder.getOrCreate()


    def readtable(dbname,table):
        dbname = dbname
        table=table
        hostname = "localhost"
        jdbcPort = 3306
        username = "root"
        password = "madhu"
        jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}?user={3}&password={4}".format(hostname,jdbcPort, dbname,username,password)
        dataframe = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',url=jdbc_url, dbtable=table).load()
        return dataframe

    t1 = readtable("db","table1")
    t2 = readtable("db2","table2")

    print(t2.show())
    spark.stop()
   ```

Please help me on how can I achieve the same.I will provide any data that will be required.

6. I have also tried with directory paths as:

   ```
    spark.eventLog.enabled      true
    spark.history.fs.logDirectory   file:///D:/tmp/spark-events
   ```

Comment: If you look at files in `D:///tmp///spark-events`, what do you see? Does your code also stop the SparkSession?

Comment: The folder D:///tmp///spark-events is empty. No file is present in it. I have stopped sparksession.

Comment: Well, if that is empty, then the error you see isn't lying... You'll need to figure out where your logs are going

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the correct master URL in the application and run the application with **spark-submit**.

You can find it in the Spark UI at `localhost:4040`
In the following example, the master URL is `spark://XXXX:7077`.
[image]

Your application should be:

```py
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("madhu").setMaster("spark://XXXX:7077")
```