# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception running Spark History Server on Windows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

According to [this page](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark-tutorial/?expand_article=1) and [this page](https://medium.com/@eyaldahari/how-to-run-spark-history-server-on-windows-52cde350de07), I should be able to launch the Spark History Server on Windows using the following Windows CMD command, issued at the Conda prompt, in the Conda environment of interest:

```
%SPARK_HOME%/bin/spark-class.cmd ^
org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
```

I installed Python 3.9 and pyspark under Anaconda, under environment *py39*, so `%SPARK_HOME%` in the above command is the following path:

```
SPARK_HOME=C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark
```

I found the path by starting the `pyspark`/Python shell and querying the environment variable.  It was *not* set at the Conda shell prompt.  For CMD commands at the Conda prompt, therefore, I manually replace `%SPARK_HOME%` with the above path.

In case it was needed, I also created the following default configuration (which is needed for `pyspark`):

```
# %SPARK_HOME%/conf/spark-defaults.conf
#--------------------------------------
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir C:\\User\\User.Name\\anaconda3\\envs\\py39\\PySparkLogs
spark.history.fs.logDirectory C:\\User\\User.Name\\anaconda3\\envs\\py39\\PySparkLogs
```

Before attempting to launch the history server, I also set the following environment variables that I normally would for a `pyspark` -- again, just in case they are needed.  At the Conda prompt for environment *py39*:

```
> set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python"
> set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=python"
> set "HADOOP_HOME=c:%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
> %SPARK_HOME%/bin/spark-class.cmd ^
   org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
```

This generates reams of errors, as listed in the Annex below.  The Conda window ends up at the Conda prompt after all these errors.  I am new to Python, Spark, Hadoop, and inexperienced in Java, but I think that the key messages from the output are:

```
23/07/28 16:36:19 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[spark-history-task-0,5,main]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
```

The last line refers to native I/O, for which I understand there are none for Windows.  Many believe that this is innocuous, e.g., as described [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/hadoop/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning/?expand_article=1) and [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread/hk0rs1gwjyv5x89890f1hy5brpdc4v8r)

To try and eke out some insight into what might be causing this error, I looked into the folder specified for `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` above.  It contains a file
`local-1690571121168` with date/time stamp "Jul 28, 2023  4:36:04 PM", i.e.,
15 seconds prior to the error messages.  I don't think the file is related to
launching the history server, as no newer file(s) result from further attempts
to launch the history server.  New files only show up when I run `pyspark` from the Conda prompt.  On that note, it doesn't seem to matter whether I have `pyspark` running in another Conda prmopt window, I get the same errors from launching the History Server.

**Other Q&A's examined**

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63322292) differs from my situation in that the person actually got the history server running.  For that question [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64996088/2153235) refers to a Master URL, which is obtained from the Spark Web UI, but I see no such URL:

[image]

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419493) addresses my problem, but the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38420497/2153235) is one of the two sources cited in the very first sentence of my question.  The second answer doesn't appear to be relevant to the error that I see.

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63598320/2153235) suggests launching the history server from `%SPARK_HOME%/sbin`.  The scripts therein, however, are for Unix shells.  The CMD scripts are in `SPARK_HOME/bin`, but running `spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer` from there makes no difference.

## Annex: Reams of errors from launching History Server

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
23/07/28 16:36:13 INFO HistoryServer: Started daemon with process name: 69808@Laptop-Hostname
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/Users/User.Name/anaconda3/envs/py39/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
23/07/28 16:36:18 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/07/28 16:36:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: User.Name
23/07/28 16:36:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: User.Name
23/07/28 16:36:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
23/07/28 16:36:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
23/07/28 16:36:18 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(User.Name); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(User.Name); groups with modify permissions: Set()
23/07/28 16:36:18 INFO FsHistoryProvider: History server ui acls disabled; users with admin permissions: ; groups with admin permissions:
23/07/28 16:36:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HistoryServerUI' on port 18080.
23/07/28 16:36:19 INFO HistoryServer: Bound HistoryServer to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://Laptop-Hostname:18080
23/07/28 16:36:19 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[spark-history-task-0,5,main]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1215)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.checkForLogs(FsHistoryProvider.scala:482)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$startPolling$3(FsHistoryProvider.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1387)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$getRunner$1(FsHistoryProvider.scala:219)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
23/07/28 16:36:24 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called

(py39) C:\Users\User.Name>
```